# Why i cannot perform requests get method on some sites

Tags: python, python-requests

I am running the following:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/')
print(r)
```

It takes forever and then i get errors when it finishes.

However, i have no issue open a web browser and enter this site.

Two questions:

1.Why it takes forever? can i control that

2.Why it fails?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should read this: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

HTTP servers are black boxes that can respond for requests as they wish - they can filter out certain requests based on on every piece of data sent in the request.

Im many cases, the response depends on the headers sent in the request.
One of the headers that are sent through the browser and is not sent by a *vanilla* python `request` is `User-Agent`.

In your case, it might help to get a response. Try:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'blah'}
response = requests.get('https://www.nasdaq.com/', headers=headers)
print(response.status_code)  # output: 200
```

You can check the headers that are sent using the browser and provide them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the nasdaq website is filtering requests based on the User-Agent of the request. Spoofing the User-Agent to Firefox makes nasdaq think that a browser is making the request & it allows the request to go through.

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://www.nasdaq.com', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'})
print(r)
```

Output:

```
<Response [200]>
```

Note that this will only download the root HTML page of the page. It will not run any JS that's embedded in it. So the downloaded page will most probably be incomplete.

Comment: Super. Much appreciate